# Unable to start webbrick again without restarting ec2 instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-12.04

I am running a rails 3.2 application on amazon ec2 in development environment and detach mode.

```
$ rails s -d
```

After this command the ec2 terminal hangs and does not come out of this command but the server starts as I can access the application.I have to close the terminal and the server remains started.

After this I kill the application.

```
$ lsof|grep 3000
$ kill -9 <pid>
```

Now if I try to restart the server, it gives error.

```
A server is already running. Check /home/ubuntu/trade_ship/tmp/pids/server.pid.
Exiting
```

Now even if I delete the tmp folder and recreate it, the server won't start. Can anyone help me with these two issues?

Answer (score 0):

Even I had faced that issue, try to restart your system and then check.. this solution worked for me at that time.

Comment: Thanks rank. Yes, restarting the server helps and but I need a permanent solution.

Comment: If again you face this problem then use kill -9 <pid>(which is in tmp/pid/sessions.id) rather than deleting the tmp folder.

Comment: I had just checked it, it works. Dont delete tmp file explicitly. I am using ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you are not able to use port 3000 use `rails s -p <port no>` command

Second is if you have to kill the RUBY instance which server started so use

```
    ps aux | grep ruby
username       17731   0.1  1.6  3127008  67996   ??  S     2:00PM   0:01.42 /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby script/rails s -d
```

and then kill

```
kill -9 17731
```

This will definitely solve the issue

Comment: Thanks Magnum. It's also not helping may be because we are doing noting new here. We are simply killing the process using command 'kill -9 <pid>' . Just the ways by which we get the pid are different. All three methods namely; ps aux | grep ruby , lsof|grep 3000 and tmp/pid/sessions.id( @rank's )  return the same pid.